# Postgresql function return trigger

Tags: postgresql, function, database-trigger

I am having a problem with a trigger. I created a trigger and a function 
for when performing an INSERT update a field in the same table. 
Is returning:

> Error: function "loss_func" in FROM has return type trigger that is
>   not     supported LINE 1: SELECT * FROM table.loss_func ()

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loss_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS $loss_func$
  BEGIN
     NEW.dt_creation := to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');   

     RETURN NULL;
  END;
  $loss_func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION loss_func()
   OWNER TO postgres;
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_loss
  AFTER INSERT ON loss
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE loss_func();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table.loss_func ()` why are you doing this ? what are you trying to select with this? this is what causes the error. Remove it and it will try to create your trigger. The execution stopped at the first line

Comment: `AFTER` triggers can't return NULL. (can't alter values either)

Answer (score 2):

A working version of your code. 
- The trigger now fires `BEFORE` insert and updates the value of `dt_creation` and returns the `NEW` version of the record :

```
drop table loss;

create table loss (
id int ,
dt_created varchar);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loss_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS $loss_func$
  BEGIN
     NEW.dt_created := to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');   
     RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $loss_func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

ALTER FUNCTION loss_func()
   OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER tgr_loss
  BEFORE INSERT ON loss
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE loss_func();

insert into loss(id) values(1);
```

Another solution that i can propose to avoid the usage of a trigger is to use a default value for `dt_creation` when you create the table (and use timestamp instead of storing the date as varchar)  :

```
...
dt_creation timestamp default now(),
...
```

or you can alter your table to set the default value to `now()` :

```
alter table loss 
alter column dt_creation set default now();
```